# asp.net implicit variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, implicit-conversion

I have 2 classes which share 9 of the 10 properties. I was trying to do what you see below but getting gc does not exist in current context. I was wondering if there is

```
     if (methodId == 2)
     {
         var gc = new LblPremium(id);

     }
     else
     {
         var gc = new LblIsoReport(id);
     }

     gc.Nbr = Nbr;

    if (method == 2) { gc.Location = "Location Identification: " + pvtData.Location; }
            ..
            ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var gc = (methodId == 2)? (LblBase)new LblPremium(id) : (LblBase)new LblIsoReport(id);
```

where `LblBase` is the base class of `LblPremium` and `LblIsoReport`.

Comment: I don't think that will work the type of gc needs to be known at compile time.  You would either have to use dynamic or declare gc as some base type that blPremium and LblIsoReport both inherit from.

Comment: Any other way of doing this. I tried var gc = new Object();

if (methodId == 2)
{  but that does not seem to work either

Comment: As Ben pointed out, the type of `gc` needs to be known at compile time.

Comment: For the base class, would that be an empty based class?

Comment: No, the base class needs to have all public elements (properties/methods) that you code will use/call after `gc` assignment.

Comment: This is rather excessive for a conditional operator.  I would suggest reverting back to the `if`/`else` blocks and simply declaring `gc` outside of either of them.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring gc inside the if and else code blocks so it does not exist outside of them.

You also cannot use var variable like that the exact type need to be known at compile time.

Comment: Thanks Ben. How can I declare it outside of the if and still make it work?

Comment: You have explained why his code doesn't work, but not what he *does* need to do to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

```
var gc = new Object();
```

//start of program....

```
switch (methodId)
{


case 1:

//what you want;

break;



case 2:
 gc = new LblPremium(id);
 gc.Location = "Location Identification: " + pvtData.Location;
 gc.Nbr = Nbr;
break;

default:
gc = new LblIsoReport(id);
gc.Nbr = Nbr;

break;

}
```

Comment: It does not compile, because `Object` does not have properties `Location` and `Nbr`.

Comment: you have to add in correct place of program,otherwise you have a error.we have a little parts of code,and answer is done by that.If object don't have this propety,is a problem of a class,not from this answer.Check your class.